# Python dataframe to list/dict

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe, dtype

I have a sample dataframe as below

[image: Column_Name Datatype FirstName string LastName string Department integer EmployeeID string]

I want this dataframe converted to this below format in python so I can pass it into dtype

{
'FirstName':'string',
'LastName':'string',
'Department':'integer',
'EmployeeID':'string',   }

Could anyone please let me know how this can be done.

To note above: I need the exact string **{'FirstName': 'string', 'LastName': 'string', 'Department': 'integer', 'EmployeeID': 'string'}** from the exact dataframe.

The dataframe has list of primary key names and its datatype. I want to pass this primary_key and datatype combination into **concat_df.to_csv(csv_buffer, sep=",", index=False, dtype = {'FirstName': 'string', 'LastName': 'string', 'Department': 'integer', 'EmployeeID': 'string'})**

Comment: Picture are very poor medium to exchange textual data. Always copy paste it instead of loading a screenshot. This is counter productive.

Answer (score 2):

`dict`/`zip` the two series:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column_Name': ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Department', 'EmployeeID'],
    'Datatype': ['string', 'string', 'integer', 'string'],
})

mapping = dict(zip(data['Column_Name'], data['Datatype']))

print(mapping)
```

prints out

```
{'FirstName': 'string', 'LastName': 'string', 'Department': 'integer', 'EmployeeID': 'string'}
```

Comment: This code does output that exact mapping. I'm not sure what the problem is..?

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I wanted. Next step for me is --> From this output, {'FirstName': 'string', 'LastName': 'string', 'Department': 'integer', 'EmployeeID': 'string'} How can I extract only the column names. I know it is easy to do directly from dataframe. But I will be passing this string as input into our lambda and there I need to handle 2 functionality. One is dtype which is now resolved from your code. Another is I need to extract only the columns in this format --> ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Department','EmployeeID']

Comment: It's just a dict: `list(d.keys())` and `list(d.values())`...

Answer (score 1):

use [to record](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html) which is much more handy.

```
print(dict(df.to_records(index=False)))
```

Should Gives #

```
{'FirstName': 'string', 'LastName': 'string', 'Department': 'integer', 'EmployeeID': 'string'}
```

### Edit :

If you want keys alone then

```
d = dict(df.to_records(index=False))

print(list(d.keys()))
```

should Gives #

```
['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Department', 'EmployeeID']
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. 

From this output, {'FirstName': 'string', 'LastName': 'string', 'Department': 'integer', 'EmployeeID': 'string'} How can I extract only the column names in this format ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Department','EmployeeID']

Comment: Thank you but I'm getting this error [ERROR] AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Probably you messing with wrong var..Try with complete code...Updated at Edit section

Comment: Has it worked?  @Pal1989

Comment: Yes, The dict got converted to string when I passed it into lambda input. I had to convert it back to dict using ast.literal_eval and then use the above code list(d.keys()). It works likes magic! Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do an easy dict comprehension with your data:

Input data:
`data = pd.DataFrame({'Column_Name' : ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Department'], 'Datatype' : ['Jane', 'Doe', 666]})`

Dict comprehension:

`{n[0]:n[1] for n in data.to_numpy()}`

This will give you:

`{'FirstName': 'Jane', 'LastName': 'Doe', 'Department': '666'}`

There are for sure other ways, e.g. using the pandas to_dict function, but I am not very familiar with this.

Edit:
But keep in mind, a dictionary needs unique values.
Your categories (first, lastname) looks like general categories. This here will only work for a single person, otherwise you have multiple keys.

Comment: They don't want the values to be actual names but rather the datatypes the keys must be, so they won't have an issue with multiple keys.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not looking for values. I need the exact string -->  {'FirstName': 'string', 'LastName': 'string', 'Department': 'integer', 'EmployeeID': 'string'}

Comment: Yes, my anwaser is exactly what you want ... Convert a 2D dataframe in a dictionary